# StringResult+format doesn't seem to work in Webix datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, date-format, webix

I expect that `stringResult` will give me an output that corresponds to the specified `format`, but it always looks like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

[Full code here.](http://webix.com/snippet/e2f5b6be)

For example, I've tried the following config:

```
{   
  view:"datepicker", 
  stringResult:true, 
  format:"%Y-%F-%d"      
},
```

But the output is still the same. So, is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Updated]**

As mentioned by Loj, I agree with it. Thus, there are 2 solutions possible:

**1. Custom Format**

The **format property** you have used sets a date format to display in the datepicker field. So, it is just the display format and it is not actually formatted. Hence, the **stringResult** returns date as string with the default format.
In order to get the custom date in the output, you are required to add your **custom format** which will convert the date in the desired format.

```
var format = webix.Date.dateToStr("%Y-%F-%d");
```

Check the snippet [here](http://webix.com/snippet/469e2f72).

**2. Using getText()**

Using **stringResult** property in the control's configuration makes the getValue method to return raw unformatted value. Hence, instead you should use the getText() as

```
$$("custom").getText();
```

in your code to get the formatted output via stringResult.

Comment: A great explanation, but isn't the `getText()` is simpler than formatting?

Comment: Great! Thanks to you both!