# How to format data in webix toExcel()?

Tags: javascript, datatable, export, export-to-excel, webix

Is there any way to set the column format for export to Excel? Seems like it works only with original dataset. Btw, `Date` objects are exported as dates (and it's nearly OK), but I would like to export the data with the specified `format`. Is it possible? TIA

For instance, here's the datatable with the formatted columns:

```
    {
      view:"datatable", 
      id:"data",
      ...
      scheme:{      // converting numbers to the Date objects
        $init:function(obj){
          obj.year = new Date(obj.year.toString())
        }
      },
      columns:[
        { id:"title", fillspace:true },
        { id:"year", width:150, format:webix.Date.dateToStr("%M, %Y") },
        { id:"votes", width:150, format:webix.i18n.numberFormat  }
      ]
    },
    { view:"button", click:"{webix.toExcel($$('data'))}"}
```

And here's a [code sample](http://webix.com/snippet/c3d2b55d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **format property** you have used sets a date format to display in your columns. In order to get the custom date in the excel, you are required to add your custom format which will convert the date in the desired format. Check the explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982162/stringresultformat-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-webix-datepicker/39997728#39997728).

```
var format = webix.Date.dateToStr("%M, %Y");
webix.ui({
  width:550,
  rows:[
    { 
      //your code 
     columns:[
         // .....
        { id:"year", width:150, template: function(obj){ return format(obj.year)}},
        // ....
      ]
    }
   //your code for the button
});
```

Please check the snippet [here](http://webix.com/snippet/e656b131).